# python: langton's ant pygame first step issues

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to make a graphic representation of the Langton's ant algorithm but I'm stuck.

here's a [Langton's Ant video description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1X-gtr4pEBU)

This is what the output should look like:

[image: Animation of first 200 steps of Langton's ant]

My code:

```
import pygame
width = 800
height = 600

display = display=pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.init()

direction = "up"

pixel_width_height = 2
qg = pixel_width_height
x=400
y=300

display.fill((0,0,0))
pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(x,y,qg,qg))
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    try:
        a = display.get_at((x, y))
    except:
        break
    if a == (255, 255, 255, 255) or a == (230, 230, 230, 255):
        if direction == "right":
            direction = "up"
            y=y-qg
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(x,y,qg,qg))
        elif direction == "up":
            direction = "left"
            x = x-qg
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(x,y,qg,qg))
        elif direction == "left":
            direction = "down"
            y=y+qg
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(x,y,qg,qg))
        elif direction == "down":
            direction = "right"
            x = x+qg
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(x,y,qg,qg))
    elif a == (255,0,0,255):
        if direction == "right":
            direction = "down"
            y=y+qg
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(x,y,qg,qg))
        elif direction == "up":
            direction = "right"
            x = x+qg
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(x,y,qg,qg))
        elif direction == "left":
            direction = "up"
            y = y-qg
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(x,y,qg,qg))
        elif direction == "down":
            direction = "left"
            x=x-qg
            pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(x,y,qg,qg))
    pygame.display.update()
print "end"
```

When it starts the ant goes in the upper left corner and then the program stops.
I really don't understand why it doesn't work.. any clue on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first draw and then update the coordinates.

Your code instead first updates the coordinates and then draws (and this means that the next move will not depend on the color you are moving to).

The difference is important because when done correctly instead next move depends on the color the ant lands in and the direction the ant is coming from; in your version except for the first move the color of the board is never used because you're painting the square and then making an `if` on its content (that's the color you just used).

You need to change the code from

```
        y=y-qg
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(x,y,qg,qg))
```

swapping the two lines to get

```
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(x,y,qg,qg))
        y=y-qg
```

**in all the places** you are updating the coordinates.

Another error is that the screen should be filled with white `(255,255,255)` at the beginning of the simulation (current code uses `(0, 0, 0)` instead).

With these changes the simulation works like in the video.

Note that you could use a different approach that scales much better to more complex cases (more than two colors). The idea is to keep an array of `directions` and an index to the current `direction`; this way to turn left or right you just need to increment or decrement the `direction` (modulo 4).

```
import pygame
width, height = 800, 600
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.init()
qg = 2
x, y = 400, 300
display.fill((255,255,255))
directions = ((0, -1), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0))
direction = 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    # update position
    dx, dy = directions[direction]
    x += dx * qg
    y += dy * qg

    try:
        a = display.get_at((x, y))
    except:
        break

    if a == (255, 255, 255, 255):
        # White square
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,0,0),(x,y,qg,qg)) # paint red
        direction = (direction + 1) % 4                 # turn left
    else:
        # Red square
        pygame.draw.rect(display,(255,255,255),(x,y,qg,qg)) # paint white
        direction = (direction + 3) % 4                     # turn right
    pygame.display.update()
print "end"
```

Comment: @LiamGiannini: See updated answer. There's also another minor error... screen should be initialized with `(255, 255, 255)`

Comment: @LiamGiannini: You made some other mistake while modifiying the code in the question probably. I tested it before updating the answer and works correctly, you can check downloading my modified version from http://raksy.dyndns.org/ant.py